# How do I describe an externally-assigned JavaScript class property for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some (JavaScript, not TypeScript) code like this:

```
export default class X {
    m() {
        this.onM();
    }
}
```

I'm using `tsconfig.json` with `allowJs`, `checkJs`, `noEmit` to validate my JS code.

I get a TypeScript error `Property onM doesn't exist on type X`.
This property is set externally, so there is nothing in the class itself assigning to it.

How do I describe this property (using JSDoc?) so that this error is solved?
I don't want to change my code just for type checker, so I don't want to stub it in the constructor.

Comment: _This property is set externally_ - how so?

Comment: Something like this:
`const x = new X(); x.onM = () => {}; x.m();`

Comment: what? If Typescript complains about the types this is Typescript?

Comment: @JonasWilms No, with `allowJs` and `checkJs` TypeScript can validate JS as well, using JSDoc for type annotations.

Comment: @andrey ah okay, never used that because I guess then it will still be easier to add some typescript annotations then you don't have a mixed codebase.

Comment: Adding something like `onM() { throw new Error('Not implemented'); }` wouldn't be a change only for the type checker IMHO. It also clarifies the code.

Comment: @sroes This is fair, but I'm still interested if it can be a pure annotation.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin I suspect the "proper" solution is to define a class that _extends_ `X`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a field declaration for any such properties. If you don't set the field Typescript will emit no code for the field, but it will recognize that the field exists. If someone sets it from an outside source it will work fine.

```
export default class X {
    onM: () => void;
    m() {
        this.onM(); // Possibly add a null check, maybe nobody actually assigned the field
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- however my question is about a JS class, not TS -- I'm not doing the emit. I'll update the post to clarify.

Comment: ... but it is probably better to initialize the property directly as one might get runtime exceptions otherwise ...

Comment: @andrey umm ... thats a Typescript error so it has to be resolved in typescript?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  Yep sorry about that, added some clarification.

Comment: @JonasWilms Most of the other stuff can be done with JSDoc, e.g. `@param {string} x`, `@type {string}`, etc.